# can we send traces from angular ui to spring boot backend while making api call

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jaeger

I have an angular app from which I want to send traces along with tags while making api calls to spring boot backend is this possible?

```
    const span = opentracing.globalTracer().startSpan("operation");
    span.setTag("tag","tagname") // this tagname I need to extract in spring boot backend when made get/post call
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to add instrumentation to your application, such as `@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-web` or https://github.com/jufab/opentelemetry-angular-interceptor. Both have extensive documentation on how to install and configure them.